# Making TinyMCE image pick dialog point to a default folder on Plone

Tags: image, tinymce, plone

Plone 4.1.

What would be the easiest way to make TinyMCE image picker dialog point to a site default folder (/image-bank) instead of current folder?

This + folder display as album would provide a rudimentary image bank support for Plone easily.

I'd hope to achieve this feature for

- All Plone out of the box content types (ATContentTypes)
- My custom AT content types
- MY custom Dexterity content types
- Portlet editor WYSIWYG (is it zope.formlib?)

If it's difficult to edit Python code all over the places, it's accetable just to a Javascript snippet patching TinyMCE settings on the client side.

Comment: Please specify whether you want to use TinyMCE with an Archetypes TextField or a plone.app.textfield field.

Comment: Ok, clarified differentn use cases

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mikko: What a coincidence. I'm just trying to achieve the same thing. I managed to create a more specific adapter than [`` `Products/TinyMCE/adapters/Upload/Upload ``](http://svn.plone.org/svn/collective/Products.TinyMCE/trunk/Products/TinyMCE/adapters/Upload.py)`.

This new adapter changes the upload folder (by setting `self.context`) to the central-images-folder and then updates radio button listing (and image preview) with the central-folder images (and just uploaded image). This is done by defining an `uploadOk` method inside the new adapter.

However, to change the initial folder, I think the only way is to customize `ploneimage.html.pt` or `ploneimage.js` inside the `skins/tinymce/plugins/ploneimage` folder. But changing any of these two **large** files (which might change in the future), could make new releases of TinyMCE not to work with your changes. So you will be forced to re-customize them again.

My idea (which I already emailed this morning to Four Digits) is to provide this feature with TinyMCE out-of-the-box, via a configuration option. This way the package files would be always aware of this feature and future changes won't harm this new functionality.

Comment: Can you  just load your own Javascript file after TinyMCE which would do required changes by manipulating Javascript run-time environment or DOM?

Comment: The problem is that JavaScript files used by ploneimage plugin are called from ploneimage.html.pt template (http://svn.plone.org/svn/collective/Products.TinyMCE/trunk/Products/TinyMCE/skins/tinymce/plugins/ploneimage/ploneimage.htm.pt) and I don't know if there's an easy way to load your custom JS after that. That's why I suggested modifying the template or the JS.

Comment: Looks ugly - fixing TinyMCE on a higher level seems to be only option, because overriding nested skins folder does not work.

Comment: What do you mean by "higher level"?

Comment: "I think the only way is to customize ploneimage.html.pt or ploneimage.js inside the skins/tinymce/plugins/ploneimage folder."   Went to the ploneimage.js file and it is really difficult to figure out how to change the default path of the uploads in this file.    Can you advise?   Thank you very much.