# Is there a plone product to bundle a page with attached files and images and handle it like one object?

Tags: plone, plone-4.x

More or less we have the same problem as [Plone - Best practice on where to store image and file attachments in pages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9297081/plone-best-practice-on-where-to-store-image-and-file-attachments-in-pages).

We move away from a Zope-based installation, where we have a selfmade object, that bundles a page and arbitary files in one directory, say:

```
http://plone.site.example.com/path/to/object
 .../index.html
 .../image.png
 .../image2.png
 .../archive.tgz
```

One can import / export / delete / copy / paste / ... the object and all included files as one object.

Is there something similiar in Plone?

We want to store, for instances images linked from one pages, near the page itself. Hide them from navigation automatically. Publish them all at once through Plone workflows, create translations and create working copies with all attached files. Hence, all normal Plone actions should transparently "just" work.

Is there some product already, that adds such enhanced "Page"-type?

The variant with the global image folder has the drawback, that images are left, then the referencing page is deleted, images and pages do not have the same published state automatically, a.s.o.

The variant with the local image has the drawback, that you need to handle the state per image, too, and you need to remember to hide them from navigation.

Answer (score 1):

we're using [raptus.article](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/raptus.article.default/) for this purpose. articles are folderish and can hold images/files and other articles (no need for default-pages on folders ;-).
you also get a preview image (similar to collective.leadimage) and you can enable and disable so called components (which are viewlets that can be managed per-object) and also register your own.

this allows you to show the teaserimage full width above the title or float-right next to the description or show a gallery of contained images below the text.

for some components (eg the gallery) you can even define which images should not show up in the gallery (ie. if you're using them in the textfield)

the only drawback i see: it's still based on archetypes

Answer (score 0):

plone.app.mosaic is trying to solve parts of this, not everything is working right now but is trying to get there.

So there will be a solution in the future.

On the meantime dexterity custom content types plus some event handlers to keep workflows a.s.o in sync could be a reasonable option maybe.